# proFTPd issues to update WordPress Plugins, etc after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates, mysql, wordpress

I have a proFTPd issues to update WordPress Plugins, etc after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

```
2021-02-20 18:30:17,270 alm.i4ware.fi proftpd[5595] template.cs1local (localhost[::1]): mod_sql/4.3: unrecoverable backend error: (1264) Out of range value for column 'bytes_in_used' at row 1
2021-02-20 18:30:17,270 alm.i4ware.fi proftpd[5595] template.cs1local (localhost[::1]): mod_sql/4.3: check the SQLLogFile for more details
```

I do the updates of WordPress Plugins, etc. trough Web-browser and all updates fail create folder and also new Plugin installations.

What to do?

Comment: This is very much a SQL error: either an overflow or a column trigger is preventing a value from being written into the `bytes_in_used` column. Grab your preferred SQL editor and change the datatype or remove the trigger 

Comment: Hi, that helped me a lot. Data type was int without size. And now everything works as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer is to set size 12 for data type int on column bytes_in_used.